# My Typo3 website takes the code from gzip js file from Compressor folder instead of my Original File

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

Please help  me to resolve my below issue in Typo3.

I have a website which is running in Typo3 CMS, and I have no admin back end access but I have all the code access. I have done the changes is one of my extension but the website is not reflecting, because the CMS is taking the code from Compressor folder js files.

Please any Typo3 experts help me on this.

Regards
Krijesh PV.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide yourself back-end access if you have access to the code of the TYPO3 installation.

**Accessing the install tool**

1. Create the `typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` file.
2. Login on `typo3/install/` with a random password and copy the given `hash`.
3. Override the install tool password in `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` with the given hash from the previous step.

Example of typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}


$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['linstallToolPassword'] = 'your hash'; // paste your hash here
```

4. Now log in with your own password.

**Create backend administrator user**

Now you're having access in the install tool you can create a new administrator user.

1. Create a new administrator user under `Important actions` in the install tool.
2. Log in with your credentials via `typo3/`

**Resolving your problem**

Since this has something to do with caching you should start to try the `Flush general caches` and `Flush front-end caches` option in the back-end. This options are hidden under the `lightning shift` icon in the top right.

If this does not result in a solution you should try the `clear all caches` option in the install tool (again under `Important actions`).

And last but not least you can remove the full content of `typo3temp/`. But make sure you don't delete the folder (then the site will go down) and you need to fix the `folder structure` (this can be done under `Folder structure` in the install tool).

**Note**

When you finish your work you need to remove your custom install tool password from `AdditionalConfiguration.php`. And may consider to remove your back-end account as well.

Good luck!